# Why doesn't this CSS Position Rule have any Effect on the P element

Tags: css

I am trying to teach myself CSS layout and I cannot understand why this css rule does not effect the position of the paragraph element.

HTML

```
     <body>


    <p>Liza likes to call me first thing in the morning at 6am, it is    very funny.</p>

   <p class"relative">I drove a Lithuanian girl home this week and she told me about the clubs that she likes to go to like Raduga and Roka club.</p>

    <p>I was sleeping all day yesterday and all night last night, I just woke up and I want to get a coffee now</p>

     </body>
```

css

```
       p  {  background-color: pink;
             border-style: solid;
             border-radius: 5px;
             padding: 10px;
             border-color:red;
             margin:20px;}

        .relative {  position: relative;
                     left: 20px;
                     top: 20px;}
```

Comment: ` class="relative"`?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see you were missing `class="relative"` there should be equal to in between. And one more suggestion. Please don't use any positions name in your class.  [Check how to name class](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-naming-conventions-that-will-save-you-hours-of-debugging-35cea737d849/)

```css
p {
  background-color: pink;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

p.relative {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <p>Liza likes to call me first thing in the morning at 6am, it is very funny.</p>

  <p class="relative">I drove a Lithuanian girl home this week and she told me about the clubs that she likes to go to like Raduga and Roka club.</p>

  <p>I was sleeping all day yesterday and all night last night, I just woke up and I want to get a coffee now</p>

</body>
```

Comment: That is a typo (the missing `=`), and we don't answer those as they are completely useless to other users, instead we use the built-in "vote/flag to close as a typographical error"